# How to create setting section for dnn9 template?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

I want to create a template for dnn9 that has a settings section. There is no explanation about it in the [dnn document](https://dnndocs.com/content/tutorials/themes/creating-themes/designers-creating-themes-overview/index.html) .

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "template"?

Comment: Themes do not have any native DNN support for "Settings"

Comment: @ Michael_Tobisch   Skin